# How I can launch my app in startup device with cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, startup

I want launch the app on startup, how I can it?

I learn about https://github.com/olaferlandsen/cordova-plugin-autostart
but it don't work well

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [cordova-plugin-autostart](https://github.com/ToniKorin/cordova-plugin-autostart) to auto start you application.

Step by step:

**Install the latest version of the plugin from CLI:**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-autostart@latest
```

**Or from master branch:**

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/ToniKorin/cordova-plugin-autostart.git
```

**Enable autoStart:**

```
cordova.plugins.autoStart.enable();
```

**Example Ionic2:**

FILE: **app.component.ts**

```
declare let cordova : any;
export class MyApp {
    rootPage:any = HomePage;
    constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            cordova.plugins.autoStart.enable();
```